# Correct implementation of scipy.optimize to solve all parameters for a plane equation

Tags: python, scipy

A three dimensional plane equation is defined as :

```
a * x + b * y + c * z + d = 0
```

where x, y, and z are coordinates of data points and a, b, c, and d define the plane parameters.
I have a bunch of x,y,z data points that I know that they roughly form a plane. Now I want to fit these data points to a plane and find a,b,c,d parameters.
I have this function so far:

```
import scipy.optimize as op
def _plane(ws,x,y,z):
    cost = np.sum(ws[0]*x + ws[1]*y + ws[2]*z + ws[3])
    print cost, np.sum(ws)
    return cost
out = op.minimize(_plane,ws,args=(x,y,z),method='SLSQP',options={'maxiter':1000, 'disp':1})

ws = plane([np.mean(x),np.mean(y),np.mean(z),0.001],x,y,z)
```

Output:

```
130.78467 -0.3011288588643074
130.78467 -0.3011288588643074
130.78467 -0.3011288439631462
130.78467 -0.3011288439631462
130.78468 -0.3011288439631462
130.78467 -0.3011288439631462
-119765.375 -1024.3011288588643
-119765.375 -1024.3011288588643
-119765.375 -1024.3011288439632
-119765.375 -1024.3011288439632
-119765.375 -1024.3011288439632
-119765.375 -1024.3011288439632
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -119765.375
            Iterations: 2
            Function evaluations: 12
            Gradient evaluations: 2
out:      fun: -119765.375
     jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([-4.07030255e-01, -8.12448636e-02, -1.02381385e+03,  1.00000000e-03])
```

As you can see `cost` is always decreasing and the value of `d` never changes no matter what I give initially. Is this implementation correct?

**UPDATE:**

Using `cost = abs(np.sum(ws[0]*x + ws[1]*y + ws[2]*z + ws[3]))` solves the optimization problem and setting `method='cg'` gives best results.

Comment: Your cost function has no minimum.  For example, the cost can always be made smaller by decreasing `w[3]`.  You'll need to create a different cost function.  Are you trying to find a least-squares solution?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I think I am. I am trying to find best parameters for a, b, c, d. I think the best parameters would be the ones that `sum(a*x+b*y+c*z+d)` for all x,y,z would be as close to zero as possible.

Comment: `minimize` doesn't find the values for which the cost is closest to zero.  It tries to find the values for which the cost is, well, *minimized*, and if the cost can go negative, it will.  Your cost function has no lower bound--you can always make it more negative by making `d` more negative.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific problem of adjusting a plane to a set of points, you can use a simpler approach:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.array([(3,0,0), (0,4,0), (3,0,1),
...                    (0,4,1), (6,-4,0), (6,-4,1)])
```

Calculate the centroid and subtract it from every point.

```
>>> centroid = np.average(points, axis=0)
>>> centered = points - centroid
```

Calculate the single value decomposition of the centered point array. The vector corresponding to the third singular value is normal to the plane and it has norm 1, so you can directly use it as the a,b,c coefficients of the plane.

```
>>> _, _, vh = np.linalg.svd(centered)
>>> a, b, c = normal = vh[2]
```

The centroid must lie on the plane, so the last coefficient (d) can be calculated from the normal vector and the centroid.

```
>>> d = -normal @ centroid
>>> plane_coefficients = a, b, c, d
>>> print(plane_coefficients)
(0.8, 0.6, 0.0, -2.4000000000000004)
```